# prepared statements in luasql.postgres

Tags: postgresql, lua, prepared-statement

I'm trying to follow the example of using prepared statements in luasql found here: 
http://lists.luaforge.net/pipermail/kepler-project/2008-January/002207.html

I have luasql version 2.2.0 installed.

When I try the example code, I get the following error message:

> lua: postgrestest.lua:63: attempt to call method 'gettypes' (a nil
>   value) stack traceback:
>           postgrestest.lua:63: in main chunk
>           [C]: ?

Here's the code:

```lua
require "luasql.postgres"
local databasename = "test"
local databaseUser = "user"
local databasepassword = "password"
local databaseserver="10.10.10.10" -- only rqd for remote database servers.
--local databaseserver="127.0.0.1"
local databaseport = 5432 -- only rqd for remote database servers.

env = assert (luasql.postgres())
con = assert (env:connect(databasename, databaseUser, databasepassword, databaseserver))

-- DROP ANY EXISTING PEOPLE TABLE
-- note:  con:execute() Returns: a cursor object if there are results, or the number of rows affected by the command otherwise.
res = con:execute("DROP TABLE people")

-- RECREATE PEOPLE TABLE
res = assert (con:execute[[
    CREATE TABLE people(
        id integer,
        fname text,
        lname text,
        job text
    )
]])
print ('result from create table is:'..res)
-- ADD SOME PEOPLE TO THE PEOPLE TABLE
res = assert(con:execute("INSERT INTO people " ..
    "VALUES (1, 'Roberto', 'Ierusalimschy', 'Programmer')"), "record inserted")
print ("result from insert"..res)

res = assert(con:execute("INSERT INTO people " ..
    "VALUES (3, 'Taylor', 'Swift', 'Singer')"))

-- RETRIEVE THE PEOPLE TABLE SORTED BY LAST NAME INTO CURSOR
cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT * from people order by lname")

-- LOOP THROUGH THE CURSOR AND PRINT
print()
print(string.format("%15s  %-15s %-15s %-15s",
    "#", "FNAME", "LNAME", "JOB"))
print(string.format("%15s  %-15s %-15s %-15s",
    "-", "-----", "-----", "---"))
row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
while row do
    print(string.format("%15d  %-15s %-15s %-15s",
        row.id, row.fname, row.lname, row.job))
    row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
end
print()

-- prepared statements 
types = con:gettypes()
stmt, err = con:prepare("select * from people where lname=$1", types["text"])
if err then
    print("problems creating prepared statement"..err)
else
    cur, err = stmt:execute("Swift")
  if err then
        print("Couldn't execute the statement: "..err);
    else
        results = cur:fetch({}, "a")
        while results do
            print(results.id)
        end
    end
end 
-- CLOSE EVERYTHING
cur:close()
con:close()
env:close()
```

I've also tried to change the prepare statement to look like this instead:

```
--types = con:gettypes()
--stmt, err = con:prepare("select * from people where lname=$1", types["text"])
stmt, err = con:prepare("select * from people where lname=$1", "Swift")
if err then
    print("problems creating prepared statement"..err)
else
    --cur, err = stmt:execute("Swift")
    cur, err = stmt:execute()
  if err then
        print("Couldn't execute the statement: "..err);
```

But I get the same error message, except with the prepare method:

```
lua: postgrestest.lua:65: attempt to call method 'prepare' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        postgrestest.lua:65: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong/ how to troubleshoot this?  Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

The connection to the database and all other code works.  The code that loops through the table and prints the data works.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are not getting a connection.

Comment: I am getting a connection because any print statements I add to show the table I just created works.  I'll update my post to include that

Comment: Are you sure that you applied the patch correctly? Seems to me that you failed during that.

Comment: yes... i assumed the patch was incorporated into the latest version of luasql... but i guess it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to apply a patch that apparently you don't have.  However, if you need to use prepared statements outside of a language framework that supports them, you can use PostgreSQL's server-side prepared statements manually.

Basically you declare your stored procedure in SQL and then call it in SQL as you would a function.  A prepared statement is sort of like a temporary SQL-language function.  So thrugh any SQL interface you can still do something like:

```
PREPARE my_insert(int, int, text, text) AS
INSERT INTO foo(id, bar, baz, test)
values ($1, $2, $3, $4);
```

Then you can call it repeatedly (with the same plan):

```
EXECUTE my_insert(1, 3, 'foo', 'bar');
```

This allows you to do such prepared statements even if your client-side framework does not support them.